# Validation system for openssl hmac code using nist vector values as input

Tags: c, openssl, cryptography, hmac

I have wrote a c code which takes the input value of key and message makes call to openssl hmac functions and generate result of mac code.
Input values are collected from NIST Test Vectors

```
#define KEY_SIZE 11         // in bytes
#define MSG_SIZE 129          // in bytes
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/hmac.h>

void str2hex(char *, char*, int);

int main() {
   char *key, *msg;
   unsigned char keyy[KEY_SIZE], msgt[MSG_SIZE], temp[4];
   unsigned char* result;
   unsigned int i, len = 20,Tlen = 10;

   key = "";//values specified below
   msg ="";//values specified below
   /*CONVERT STRING TO HEX DIGITS - KEY*/
   str2hex(key, keyy, KEY_SIZE);
  //CONVERT STRING TO HEX DIGITS - MSG*//
   str2hex(msg, msgt, MSG_SIZE);


   result = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * len);

   HMAC_CTX ctx;
   HMAC_CTX_init(&ctx);


   HMAC_Init_ex(&ctx, keyy, strlen(keyy), EVP_sha1(), NULL);
   HMAC_Update(&ctx, (unsigned char*)&msgt, strlen(msgt));
   HMAC_Final(&ctx, result, &len);
   HMAC_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);

   printf("HMAC digest: ");

   for (i = 0; i < Tlen; i++)
    printf("%02x", result[i]);

   printf("\n");

   free(result);

   return 0;
}
//=====================  string to hex conversion 
================================//

void str2hex(char *str, char *hex, int len) {
  int tt, ss;
  unsigned char temp[4];
  for (tt = 0, ss = 0; tt < len, ss < 2 * len; tt++, ss += 2) {
    temp[0] = '0';
    temp[1] = 'x';
    temp[2] = str[ss];
    temp[3] = str[ss + 1];

    hex[tt] = (int) strtol(temp, NULL, 0);
  }
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
```

The first input given:

```
Key = 82f3b69a1bff4de15c33
Msg = fcd6d98bef45ed6850806e96f255fa0c8114b72873abe8f43c10bea7c1df706f10458e6d4e1c9201f057b8492fa10fe4b541d0fc9d41ef839acff1bc76e3fdfebf2235b5bd0347a9a6303e83152f9f8db941b1b94a8a1ce5c273b55dc94d99a171377969234134e7dad1ab4c8e46d18df4dc016764cf95a11ac4b491a2646be1
```

Output generated:

```
 HMAC digest: 1ba0e66cf72efc349207
```

Nist_Mac = 1ba0e66cf72efc349207

It matches so success

But for the Second input

```
Key = 4766e6fe5dffc98a5c50
Msg = d68b828a153f5198c005ee36c0af2ff92e84907517f01d9b7c7993469df5c21078fa356a8c9715ece2414be94e10e547f32cbb8d0582523ed3bb0066046e51722094aa44533d2c876e82db402fbb00a6c2f2cc3487973dfc1674463e81e42a39d9402941f39b5e126bafe864ea1648c0a5be0a912697a87e4f8eabf79cbf130e
```

Output generated:

```
 HMAC digest: ca96f112a79882074b63
```

Nist_Mac = 007e4504041a12f9e345

Its failing.If any one could check my code and kindly let me know what am i doing wrong it will be really helpfull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues here.

The first is that you're using `strlen` on an array of characters that may contain a null byte.  Since this function counts the number of bytes until it find a null byte, you won't get what you expect if your array contains a null byte (as is the case for your second example).

Instead of using `strlen` on the byte array to determine the length, use the actual length of the data.  Since you're converting a string containing hex digits to bytes, the length of the byte array is half the length of the input string.

```
HMAC_Init_ex(&ctx, keyy, strlen(key)/2, EVP_sha1(), NULL);
HMAC_Update(&ctx, msgt, strlen(msg)/2);
```

Note also that you should pass `msgt` to `HMAC_Update`, not `&msgt`, as the latter is a pointer to an array.

The second issue is in your `str2hex` function.  When you construct `temp`, you don't have enough space for a terminating null byte.  This causes `strtol`, which expects a null-terminated string, to read past the end of the array.  This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

In this particular case  you're "lucky" that it works, as the byte in memory that follows `temp` happens to contain either a null byte or a non-digit.  You can't however depend on this behavior.  Fix this by making `temp` one byte longer and explicitly setting that byte to 0.  And while you're at it, you should also fix the signed / unsigned mismatch in your function arguments and change the type of `temp` to an `unsigned char` array.

```
void str2hex(char *, unsigned char*, int);

...

void str2hex(char *str, unsigned char *hex, int len) {
  int tt, ss;
  char temp[5];
  for (tt = 0, ss = 0; tt < len, ss < 2 * len; tt++, ss += 2) {
    temp[0] = '0';
    temp[1] = 'x';
    temp[2] = str[ss];
    temp[3] = str[ss + 1];
    temp[4] = 0;

    hex[tt] = strtol(temp, NULL, 0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At byte position 58 in the message, you have a 0x00 byte (null). Since you're doing an `strlen(msgt)`, this results in 58 instead of 128. Excerpt from the documentation (emphasis mine):

> The C library function `size_t strlen(const char *str)` computes the length of the string str **up to, but not including the terminating null character**.

Just use the proper length of the message and don't use string operations on char arrays that do not contain printable bytes.